# Parsing text file using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a continuously changing text file that contains messages from the Gmail API. I need to parse the contents of it. My text file contains the id of the message, the message, sender details and the date:

```
15335b114b093448(message id)::NAME : SINDHUJA, 
SERVICE REQUIRED: PLUMBER ,CITY :BANGALORE, EMAIL ID : sinducj@gmail.com , MOBILE : 9987654434::  Wed, 02 Mar 2016 04:58:29 +0000::Flipkart(partner) mail@flipkartletters.com:::

 15335254a7e5677a::NAME : HALEN, 
SERVICE REQUIRED: ELECTRICIAN ,CITY :CHENNAI, EMAIL ID : shbucj@gmail.com ,MOBILE : 934554434:: ::Wed, 2 Mar 2016 07:36:37 +0530 (IST)::The Times of India mailerservice@timesofindia.com::::
```

How do I parse it? I tried the code:

```
 >>>rawProfiles='''
    15335b114b093448::NAME : SINDHUJA, 
SERVICE REQUIRED: PLUMBER ,CITY :BANGALORE, EMAIL ID : sinducj@gmail.com ,MOBILE : 9987654434::  Wed, 02 Mar 2016 04:58:29 +0000::Flipkart <mail@flipkartletters.com>:::
    15335254a7e5677a::NAME : HALEN, 
SERVICE REQUIRED: ELECTRICIAN ,CITY :CHENNAI, EMAIL ID : shbucj@gmail.com ,MOBILE : 934554434:: ::Wed, 2 Mar 2016 07:36:37 +0530 (IST)::The Times of India <mailerservice@timesofindia.com>::::
    '''
    >>>profilesList=re.split(r'\n{1,}',rawProfiles)

    >>>profilesList =[re.sub(r'\n',' ',profile) for profile in profilesList]

    >>>profilesList =[re.split(r',',profile,maxsplit=2) for profile in profilesList]
    >>>for profile in profilesList:
    print profile

    >>>profilesList =[map(str.strip,profile) for profile in profilesList]
    >>>for profile in profilesList:
    print profile
```

This gave me a: `nameError re not defined`.

*EDIT*

The code is in python.

My sample output should be :

```
 PARTNER       NAME       SERVICE     CITY        MOBILE     EMAIL  
Flipkart    SINDHUJA    PLUMBER    BANGALORE    9987654434  sinducj@gmail.com 
  Times      HALEN     ELECTRICIAN  CHENNAI      9345544342   shbucj@gmail.com
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include example output. And just out of interest, what language is that code?

Comment: Sorry but your post is very hard to read. Please use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to make your text appear like code. We need to see exactly what the actual ionput data look like.

Comment: @terdon I have edited it...!

Comment: Please use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) as I asked and not HTML markup. Do you really want empty lines between each line of output? Do you really need the headers in bold? We need to see _exactly_ what you want.

Comment: @terdon i jus need the fields of every message separately ... how do i do it ? And the message should be parsed without being case sensitive..

Comment: Why in the second line you just want to print "times" and not "The Times of India"?

Comment: @terdon yes the whole thing needs to be printed...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small problem with the Partner column of the second line, but this awk can serve you as a beginning.

```
BEGIN {
    FS="::";
    OFS="\t";
    print "PARTNER\tNAME\tSERVICE\tCITY\tMOBILE\tEMAIL"
}
{
    split($2,A,"[:,]");
    if ($3 == " ")
    {
        split($5,B,"[:,]");
    }
    else
    {
        split($4,B,"[:,]");
    }

    split(B[1],C,"mail");
    name=A[2];
    service=A[4];
    city=A[6];
    mobile=A[10];
    email=A[8];
    partner=C[1];
    sub("[(]partner[)]", "",partner);

    print partner"\t"name"\t"service"\t"city"\t"mobile"\t"email;
}
```

Out:

```
PARTNER NAME    SERVICE CITY    MOBILE  EMAIL
Flipkart     SINDHUJA    PLUMBER    BANGALORE    9987654434  sinducj@gmail.com 
The Times of India   HALEN   ELECTRICIAN    CHENNAI  934554434   shbucj@gmail.com
```

You have to run it from the (bash,zsh..)shell and save it as whatever.awk

`awk -f whatever.awk file`

Comment: I am a newbie to awk...Where do i run this code ? in the python shell ? Thank you for the efforts !

Comment: @Indhuja I just edit it.

Comment: For most file types, with some exceptions, awk is best to process text. And, it is installed by default in unix and now in linux.

Comment: Thank you !!! where do i mention the name of the text file to parse? @Firefly

Comment: `awk -f script.awk FileToParse`

Comment: awk -f tri.awk foo5 
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Indhuja check carriage returns in the awk script and make sure the file to parse is in UTF8

Comment: The text file that needs to be parsed here need not be in the same order...Like  the service , city , name can be shuffled depending upon the message being sent to my gmail api...How do i manage that ? @firefly

Comment: @Indhuja you keep adding extra requirements in the comments. Please don't do that. Take some time and think about what you need and ask a question with an example that is representative of all cases you need to deal with.

Comment: @terdon oops i apologise for that !